# Scaling all UI elements with respect to aspect ratio to fit screen - Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I have made UI for my app which looks like this:

[image]

All elements are raster and their size is made to fit my phone's resolution, which they do nicely. However I would like to have this UI scalable to any screen resolution while maintaining aspect ratio. I have tried some approaches but to no avail. How would you guys do this? Can you point me to right direction ? Thanx

Comment: Are you rendering the images yourself or using the built-in UI widgets (Button, CheckBox, ...) with alternate backgrounds?

Comment: They are all default ImageView. I just want them all to stay togeather, not breaking apart or glitching while stretching to fit screen.

Comment: I would recommend that you turn the background of the buttons into a Nine-patch, switch the ImageViews out with Buttons, and use the nine-patch as a background for those buttons. You would also have to add the font to your application, and setup the styling for the font color. Read more about nine-patches here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

you have to :

- **Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application supports:** "Declaring support for different screen sizes can also affect how the system draws your application on larger screens—specifically, whether your application runs in screen compatibility mode."
- **Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities**  "if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities."
- **Provide different layouts for different screen sizes**

for more details : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: so there is nothing that can achieve behaviour like this? http://jsfiddle.net/T6PvL/

Comment: providing different bitmaps to support low, medium, high and extra-high density screens will help you to achieve good graphical quality and performance on all screen densities.

Comment: read this for more info:http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: I just need to fit my ui to cover whole screen regardless of resoulution, thats all.

Comment: please put your XML inside your question, to see if can help